# Android list row: image+text+image

Tags: android, design-patterns, layout

I'm creating a list of items with a personalized layout for the rows. In each row I want to have two images of fixed size:

- one must contact its left border with the left border of the row layout (red square).
- the other one must contact its right border with the right border of the row layout (orange square)

In between these images I want to have some extra elements inside a layout (green area). Thus, the size of this layout should be match_parent, but without hiding neither of the previous two images.

[image]

How can I do this?

I'm trying to put three linear layouts, wrapping to width the first and the third, and matching_parent the green one, but the green is hidding the orange.

EDIT: This is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_A"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="70dp"
                android:minHeight="70dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_A_24" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_textA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_textB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbl_num"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_B"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:minWidth="30dp"
                android:minHeight="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_B_24" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are they ImageView, TextView and ImageView respectively with white background? Why should they be match_parent? I think you're looking for `android:layout_weight`.

Comment: Actually I have more things than just a TextView in the middle (See the edit in my post). The problem is that if the text in these textviews is not long enough, the layer in the middle shrinks, and so the image in the right goes to the left instead of being next to the right border of all the layout.